# Checkbox checked with js map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing some kind of survey, and creating questions and choices based on api response, using map to handle checkbox onChange, it works very well. However, I am unable to make checkbox checked properly.

Here is checkbox

```
<FormControlLabel 
       key={choice.choiceID}
       value={choice.choiceID}
       control={<Radio />}
       label={choice.text}
       labelPlacement="end"
       name={"" + question.questionID}
       onChange={handleChange}
       checked={
       qValues1.get(question.questionID + "") === question.questionID + ""}
 />
```

I am converting questionID to string, because name prop should be string.

```
  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    qValues1.set(name, value); // adding into map, which is state
    if (qValues1.get(name) === value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I tried converting map into array, and trying to find choiceID using .includes(), but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
{qValues1.get(question.questionID + "") === question.questionID + ""}
```

You're checking if the map `qValues` contains a key matching its value. So you should do :

```
const { name, checked } = event.target
qValues1.set(name, checked ? name : undefined);
```

in `handleChange`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Material-UI, so you might want to mention that. Sometimes they change the props and stuff so it can get a little wonky. As far as your code goes it looks like your handleChange() function may be the issue. Every time I set up an onChange event I make sure to use the syntax `event.target.value` to capture the inputs. I'm not sure if that works but give it a try! I've never seen a de-structured syntax like that before in your code -- `const { name, value } = event.target;` so that's throwing me through a loop. What are your errors looking like?

Answer (score 0):

So, it will like below now, works just fine.

```
 <FormControlLabel
                          key={choice.choiceID}
                          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                          label={choice.text}
                          labelPlacement="end"
                          name={question.questionID + ""}
                          value={choice.choiceID + ""}
                        />
```

and handleChange

```
 const { name, value } = event.target;
    let { checked } = event.target;
    qValues1.set(name, checked ? value : undefined);
```